# Converting a long char array of number to byte array

Tags: c, arrays, char

How can i convert a char array of number to byte array?
Example:

```
char *digit="3224833640520308023"//long long array
```

convert to:

```
uint8_t buff[256]= {0x2c, 0xc0, 0xe9, 0x1c, 0x32, 0xf1, 0x55, 0x37, 0};

(2c c0 e9 1c 32 f1 55 37)
```

Comment: If you put your code in a separate paragraph and indent each line by at least four spaces, it'll format much nicer and it'll be much easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: What is the relationship between the contents of the char array and the contents of your uint8_t array?

Comment: I take it you want to accept a string representing a number, convert to long long, and then have it as a uint8_t array with the binary representation?  Or do you want to automatically convert it to a C statement like the one you've listed?  Do you mind indulging in what is technically undefined behavior?

Comment: Is your "digit" a group of individual ASCII characters? A giant decimal string? A group of hex digits? Please clarify...

Comment: Big number (3224833640520308023) convert to hex (2cc0e91c32f15537)

Comment: " A giant decimal string?" Yes. It's big decimal string.

Comment: A limit on the number of chars? In your example, the output fits in a 64-bit integer.

Comment: If homework, implement the division by 256 by hand for an arbitrary number. Else find some source for [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

Answer (score 1):

I printed in reverse order in the end. You may want to endian swap if you need the array in that endian order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *digit="3224833640520308023";

int  main() {
  int i;
  unsigned char byteArray[16];
  unsigned long long x = strtoull(digit,0,10);

  printf("%llx\n",x);
  printf("%llu\n",x);
  for (i=0;i<8;i++) {
    byteArray[i] = (x>>(i*8)) & 0xFF;
  }

  printf ("Array is:\n");
  for (i=7;i>=0;i--) {
    printf("%2.2x ",byteArray[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of explicitly creating each value, you can cast a reference to an array.  reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(&x)[i] (assuming endianness) should do the trick

Comment: my device print to display: 

2cc0e91c 

750840092 

Array is: 

00 00 00 00 2c c0 e9 1c

Comment: Well, yes - this was C (not C++) so the "reinterpret_cast" won't work - but I could have "(unsigned char *) (&x)"

Answer (score 0):

strtoull converts the string to a 64 bits internal representation.

htobe64 will switch the endianness to big endian (the one you used in your example) if needed on your platform.

You can then copy 8 bytes from this big endian 64bit variable to your byte array.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <endian.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *digit="3224833640520308023";

main ()
{
    uint64_t ull;
    uint64_t beull;
    uint8_t buff[8];
    int i;

    ull=strtoull(digit,0,10);
    beull=htobe64(ull);
    memcpy(buff,&beull,8);
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        printf("%02x\n",buff[i]);
    }
}
```